# Prove or disprove: if $f$ and $fg$ are continuous then $g$ is continuous.

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, continuity

Prove of provide a counterexample:

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are defined and finite valued on an open interval $I$ which contains $a$, that $f$ is continuous at $a$, and that $f(a)\neq 0$. Then $g$ is continuous at $a$ if and only if $fg$ is continuous at $a$.

I don't suppose it's true, based on the fact that the common theorem '$f, g$ continuous implies $fg$ continuous' is not stated as true both ways; obviously, this implies exceptions. The only ones I can think of, however, are one's that don't fit the "open interval" or "$f(a)\neq 0$" parts, or ones where both f and g are discontinuous.

I've also tried proving it, but with no luck.

Help? :-S

Comment: I suppose you actually meant: $\,f\,$ is a continuous function, then for a function $\,g\,$ we have that $\,fg\,$ is continuous iff $\,g\,$ is continuous.

Comment: @DonAntonio, I did not, but, maybe I'm mistaken, does that not mean the same thing? "$fg$ is continuous iff $g$ is continuous" is logically equivalent to "$g$ is continuous iff $fg$ is continuous".

Comment: you title reads "$\,f\,$ **and** $\,fg\,$ are cont. iff $\,g\,$ is continuous"...this, of course, is far from being true, but I think this is *not* what you really meant.

Comment: @DonAntonio, Ah, now I see what you meant. I was not looking at the title when I read your last comment - I thought you meant the actual proposition. I agree, the title is incorrect; it should read "Prove or disprove: if $f$ and $fg$ are continuous then $g$ is continuous" (the other direction being trivial). I'll fix it.

Comment: What does "finite valued" mean? It seems to reveal a misunderstanding of what "defined" means.

Comment: @TonyK, Can you elaborate on the "misunderstanding of what 'defined' means"?

Comment: @Alex KW: After you reveal what you mean by "finite valued". I asked first!

Comment: @TonyK, It means whatever the author of my book wants it to mean, haha. I would assume it's just to further assert/clarify that $f(x)\neq\infty$ for any $x\in I$, not that that's possible (?) anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$f$ is continuous and nonzero at $a$, hence $1/f$ is continuous at $a$.  Since $fg$ is continuous at $a$ as well, so is their product $(fg)(1/f)=g$.

(the other direction doesn't need a trick).

Comment: thank you! Seems obvious now that you've said it. #doh

Comment: How can you deduce that $f$ must be continuous on an interval around $a$?

Comment: @JavierBadia, I suppose I can't; I need $f$ to be continuous on an interval around $a$, in addition to the other assumptions stated.  Otherwise, there might be some sequence $a_1, a_2, \ldots $ with $a_i\rightarrow a$ and $f(a_i)=0$, which kills my proof.

Comment: @vadim123: No, wait. If there was such a sequence, $f$ would not be  continuous at $a$. You don't need $f$ to be continuous on an interval; I believe algebra of limits implies that if $f$ is continuous and non-zero at $a$, then so is $1/f$.

Comment: @JavierBadia Badia Yes, that's actually how I reworked the proof once you pointed that out. Simply removing the open interval around $a$ and discussing the point $a$ itself works. Thanks to you both!