# If $fg$ is continuous at $a$ then $g$ is continuous at $a$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, solution-verification

> Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are defined and finite valued on an open interval $I$ which contains $a$,
> that $f$ is continuous at $a$, and that $f(a) \neq 0$.
> If $fg$ is continuous at $a$ then $g$ is continuous at $a$.

$\underline{Attempt}$

Since $f$ is conituous at $a$ and $fg$ continuous at $a$,

$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)  \text{ and } \lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)=f(a)g(a)$$

so

$$\lim_{x\to a} {f(x)g(x)} = \lim_{x\to a}f(x) \lim_{x\to a}g(x)=f(a)\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=f(a)g(a)$$

since $f(a) \neq0$

$$\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=g(a)$$

$\therefore g$ is continuous at $a$

Comment: Here $\lim_{x\to a} {f(x)g(x)} = \lim_{x\to a}f(x) \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ you already *assume* that $ \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exists.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/409550/42969 for a correct proof.

Comment: @MartinR I saw this one thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is not correct. You are assuming existence of $\lim_{ x \to a} g(x)$ but you have to prove the existence of this limit.  Write $g(x)$ as $\frac 1 {f{(x)}} {g(x)f(x)}$ observing that $f(x) \neq 0$ if $|x-a| $ is small enough. Now you can see that the limit exists and equal $\frac {f(a)g(a)} {f(a)}=g(a)$.

[There exists $\delta >0$ such that $|x-a| <\delta$ implies  $|f(x)-f(a)| <\frac  {|f(a)|} 2$. So  $|x-a| <\delta$ implies  $|f(x)| >|f(a)| -\frac  {|f(a)|} 2=\frac  {|f(a)|} 2>0$ and so $f(x) \neq 0$].

Comment: Thank you I got the point

Comment: I think that there is a typo

Comment: @puka Sorry. I don't see where  typo is. Can you point it out?

Comment: Is it $\frac{f(a)g(a)}{f(a)}=g(a)$ ?

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @puka Yes, of course. An extra $1$ typed after '\frac' led to the mistake. Thanks for pointing out.